# How to use the same block of link_to_unless when condition is false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

How can I use the same block of the `link_to_unless` when condition is true (in place of 'Hello' in the example) without write the block two times (with an `if ... else`)?

```
<%= link_to_unless(url.nil?, 'Hello') do %>
  <%= image_tag(image_url) %>
  <h1><%= title %></h1>
  <h2><%= subtitle %></h2>
<% end %>
```

I would like to have this if `url` exists

```
<a href="url">
  <img src ... />
  <h1>...</h1>
  <h2>...</h2>
</a>
```

and the same content without the link if `url` is `nil`

```
<img src ... />
<h1>...</h1>
<h2>...</h2>
```

Comment: To display the same content,it is precise to use just `link_to` rather than `link_to_unless` or `link_to_if`.

Comment: Example @Pavan? `link_to "Hello", url` will cause exception if `url` is `nil`.

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible to do when the conditional element wraps the other elements you want displayed regardless. A solution might be to always wrap the elements with an `<a>` tag, but only add a href when a URL is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually create an helper method like this

In your application_helper.rb:

```
def conditional_link(options={}, &block)
    unless options.delete(:hide_link)
        concat content_tag(:a, capture(&block), options)
    else
        concat capture(&block)
    end
end
```

And in your view:

```
<% conditional_link(:hide_link => url.nil?, :href => "/hello" ) do %>
    <%= image_tag(image_url) %>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <h2><%= subtitle %></h2>
<% end %>
```

Assuming that your `url.nil?` does work properly by returning a boolean

You can of course pass more options to your link, for example a class or id:

```
<% conditional_link(:hide_link => url.nil?, :href => "/hello", :class => "myclass", :id => "myid" ) do %>
    <%= image_tag(image_url) %>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <h2><%= subtitle %></h2>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Interesting use of `capture(&block)`, I've not seen this before. Can you not use `yield`?

Comment: Honestly, I've used this for while and haven't thought of it...it would be a good idea to try but I have a feeling it won't work as well

Comment: Probably I haven't explained well. Your helper produce a link to `/hello` when `url` is `nil`. I need that the helper produce a link to `url` just if `url` exists, otherwise just return the block (without link). I got the behavior I expected changing `if` with `unless` in your helper.

Comment: ha! you're totally right! Just to keep proper semantic, let me change the var names as well then :)